# Menu Background Colour Wordpress for homepage only

Tags: css, menu, background

I am trying to change the background colour of a menu in Wordpress.

The background is transparent for all other pages which is good, but for the homepage where the first element on the page below is a slider the menu remains grey and I cannot seem to change it without making it opaque for the whole site?

The page/site in question is http://nudda.com/new/home-2

Comment: probably duplicate of the link below [link here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125315/style-something-only-on-the-home-page)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Wordpress for development, so you can add a specific ID to your home page, then you can use it to change the menu background just for home page,, you should do something like this:

```
#Your_ID #top-wrapper {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add custom CSS and JS plugin in case you don't have a place to add custom CSS.

Then, add this line of CSS code:

```
#top-wrapper {
    background-color: #050505 !important;
}
```

I can see that you might have already have written that but without the `!important`.

What is happening is that the default style is overwriting the new style.
The !important will allow you to force overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

simple fix is

```
.page-id-2700 #top-wrapper{
   // your background color here
 }
```

page-id-2700 is the wordpress generated page class for home